# Acceso a base de datos (registro y logueo) desde Android con scripts php

Tags: php, java, android, http

Tengo una base de datos remota y tengo problemas para acceder a ella desde mi proyecto de Android mediante scripts de php. Me da este error:

```
E/Volley: [882] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php
```

(He cambiado el nombre de la web pero es el mismo error). He dado permiso en manifest con

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

y tengo esta dependencia:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

La base de datos tiene una tabla de usuarios con 5 campos: `"userID" (clave primaria y autoincrement), "password", "v1" y "v2"`.

Los scripts de php que estoy usando, que he subido a webhost (he cmabiado las propiedades de conexión pero eso está bien, ahí no debería estar el problema):

**Login.php**

```php
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("dbHost", "dbUser", "dbPassword", "dbName");
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $username, $password, $v1, $v2);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
        $response["v1"] = $v1;
        $response["v2"] = $v2;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

***Register.php***

```php
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("dbHost", "dbUser", "dbPassword", "dbName");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $v1 = $_POST["v1"];
    $v2 = $_POST["v2"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, v1, v2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $username, $password, $v1, $v2);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

MainActivity, que es la clase de Login (no creo que necesite escribir el xml para esto, simplemente están los elementos que se usan aquí):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tvRegister = findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
        Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        final EditText etusernameLogin = findViewById(R.id.etUsernameLogin);
        final EditText etpassLogin = findViewById(R.id.etPassLogin);

        tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(register);
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etusernameLogin.getText().toString();
                final String password = etpassLogin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response){
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean ok = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (ok==true){
                                String user = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                                String v1 = jsonResponse.getString("v1");
                                String v2 = jsonResponse.getString("v2");

                                Intent userFinderIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, userFinder.class);
                                userFinderIntent.putExtra("username", user);
                                userFinderIntent.putExtra("v1", v1);
                                userFinderIntent.putExtra("v2", v2);
                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(userFinderIntent);
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                alert.setMessage("Login error").setNegativeButton("Try again", null).create().show();
                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                };
                LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest(username, password, response);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LoginRequest:

```java
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String url = "https://project.000webhostapp.com/Login.php"; // Nombre de website falso, pero el real tiene la misma estructura
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, url, listener, null);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("username", username+"");
        parameters.put("password", password+"");
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Clase Register:

```java
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText usernameRegister = findViewById(R.id.etUsernameRegister);
        final EditText passRegister = findViewById(R.id.etPassRegister);
        Button register = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = usernameRegister.getText().toString();
                String password = passRegister.getText().toString();
                String v1="a";
                String v2="b";



                    Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try{
                                JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean ok = jsonresponse.getBoolean("success");
                                if(ok==true){
                                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    Register.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
                                    Register.this.finish();
                                }else{
                                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                    alert.setMessage("Register error").setNegativeButton("Try again", null).create().show();
                                }
                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                e.getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    RegisterRequest request = new RegisterRequest(username, password, v1, v2, response);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                    queue.add(request);
                }
        });


    }
}
```

RegisterRequest:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String url = "https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php"; // Nombre de website falso, pero el real tiene la misma estructura
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, String v1, String v2, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, url, listener, null);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("username", username+"");
        parameters.put("password", password+"");
        parameters.put("v1", v1+"");
        parameters.put("v2", v2+"");
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Clase userFinder, que es simplemente una clase que he creado para probar el login:

```java
public class userFinder extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_finder);

        final TextView message = findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        Intent intentMessage = this.getIntent();
        String username = intentMessage.getStringExtra("username");
        String v1 = intentMessage.getStringExtra("v1");
        String v2 = intentMessage.getStringExtra("v2");
        message.setText("User: " + username + message.getText() + ", v1: " + v1 + message.getText() + ", v2: " + v2);
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: has probado a usar Postman sobre los archivos php para verificar que la respuesta que te da es correcta?

Comment: Estás teniendo un error 404, lo cual significa que la URL a la que estás dirigiendo la petición no existe, de hecho cuando se intenta entrar a `https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php` se verifica que no existe. Debes poner la URL correcta.

Comment: Hola como lo menciona @A. Cedano, claramente tienes un eror 404 relacionado al protocolo HTTP con el que Voley realiza la petición, por lo que debes verificar la URL `https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php` de tu proyecto y actualizarla correctamente.

Comment: Preguntas que haces para arreglar este problema con codigo 404 @Confusion , debes asegurar que exista esta página :  https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php o agrega la correcta.

Comment: Tsk pensaba que existía y por eso estaba tan liado pero ahora lo he vuelto a mirar y resulta que el sitio este no me la había creado bien porque es de pago. Existe algún sitio similar gratis?

Comment: Mi respuesta queda como un comentario a raíz de haber claramente una respuesta muy superior en contenido y fundamentación realizada por @Jorgesys...

Comment: @allexiusw Lo siento pero la respuesta del otro usuario fue un poco mejor y tengo que elegir una. Mira de nuevo, en la tuya me decías que "verificase la URL y la actualizase". ¿Qué me quieres decir con eso? ahora ya lo entiendo, pero en su momento no lo entendía. Sin embargo Jorgeys me ha dado dos comentarios un poco más completos, haciéndome entender por fin que no me había salido bien la creación de la página porque no existía.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En este caso el problema es que Volley no puede realizar la petición ya que no existe acceso a la url que especificas,

> E/Volley: [882] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code
>   404 for https://project.000webhostapp.com/Register.php

El error 404 indica que el contenido solicitado no está disponible ("404 Not Found"), este código es enviado desde el servidor a quien trato de realizar hizo la petición HTTP.